# Uploading APK build to Google Play Console error "You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle"

Tags: unity, c#, google-play, google-play-services

I was trying to upload my andoid app apk build to my play console account and I keep getting this error:

```
You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.
```

In accordance with the informations given at

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html#publishing-configure

and

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1653647/you-uploaded-a-debuggable-apk-or-android-app-bundl.html

Here are what I have done so far:

1) I have gone to the root folder of my unity project, searched for **AndroidManifest.xml**, and I found multiple Manifest files, and changed the value of **"android:debuggable"** to false for each of these manifest files that were generated by unity(and I did not edit the google generated manifest files).

2) I have scanned every c# file on my project that contains the keyword *"Debug"* and I have either deleted or commented out the *Debug.log* lines except on the files generated by google(as a result of the integration of google play services into my game).

And yet, I still have the same problem when I try to upload my apk to play console. What else am I missing? Should I also remove the *Debug.log* lines from google generated c# script files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what happened exactly, but I uploaded successfully after disabling "Enable built-in Ads extension" on Unity's Services window to fix the Unity Ad duplicate errors that I was getting in the console after a build.

Answer (score 1):

1- Firstly you have to disable the development build in your Android Build settings
uncheck the development build
2- Second in your code try to find out where you have written debugging=true
third look into your android manifest file[image]

Comment: I've already done all that and it doesn't work.

Comment: @MetaMax in your project is there any third party plugins if so then dig into them

Comment: I've already done that.

Comment: @MetaMax then there is problem with your keystore

Answer (score 1):

Go to build settings:

1. Select IL2CPP
2. Verify the C++ Compiler Configuration is set to Release
3. Check all Android manifests for `android:debuggable`.

   It should be `<application android:debuggable=false>`

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included an explanation of how and why this fixes the problem.

Comment: When you are releasing it should be in il2cpp as google need 64 bit builds now onwards and that can be made only in il2cpp.